# SQL update values based on join

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update values of one table based on criteria of second table.
But something is wrong. Can you advise what I'm a doing wrong?

```
UPDATE food_serve
SET food_serve_cost = food_serve_cost*1.15
FROM food_serve JOIN fooditem  
ON fooditem.food_item_no = food_serve.food_item_no
WHERE food_type = 'M' ;
```

Using oracle sql. Error report -

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: which db your are using ?  (sql is not a db but a query language)  and the update with join sintax is db dependent

Comment: Using oracle sql. Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended" *Cause:
*Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I think you miss something  in `food_serve_cost` You didnt use any alias

```
UPDATE ( SELECT food_serve.food_serve_cost , 
fooditem.food_serve_cost
FROM food_serve
INNER JOIN fooditem ON fooditem.food_item_no =   
food_serve.food_item_no
WHERE fooditem.food_type = 'M')
SET food_serve.food_serve_cost=fooditem.food_serve_cost*1.15
```

Or You can use merge

```
MERGE into food_serve
USING fooditem
ON (fooditem.food_item_no = food_serve.food_item_no)
when matched then update SET     
food_serve.food_serve_cost=fooditem.food_serve_cost*1.15
WHERE fooditem.food_type = 'M'
```

Comment: tried it. SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: IF my answer  helped you please mark it as a correct answer ,so that in future people can find it helpful @SanitoMachiavelli

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have ambiguous columns try add the table name for example:

```
UPDATE food_serve
SET food_serve.food_serve_cost = fooditem.food_serve_cost*1.15
FROM food_serve JOIN fooditem  
ON fooditem.food_item_no = food_serve.food_item_no
WHERE fooditem.food_type = 'M' ;
```

Comment: Sorry   i did your instead of mine please accept my apology

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Merge Operator better in this situation

```
               select * into #Target from fooditem  WHERE food_type ='M' 

                     MERGE food_serve AS T
                     USING #Target AS S 
                     ON S.food_item_no = T.food_item_no 
                     WHEN MATCHED THEN
                     UPDATE SET T.food_serve_cost = T.food_serve_cost*1.15
```

Comment: *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.